# How i can make referal url prefix with dynamic value to accessible in all website

Tags: php, laravel

For guest user i want to create specific referal link as dynamic prefix with which website can be accessed for eg `127.0.01:8000` same on `siteurl/user/{dynamic value}/`  or other front end pages with these prefix.

I have implemented  package (`mcamara`'s) but its not working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes file you can do something like this:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/user/{code?}'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'ReferralCode@code');
});
```

Then in your controller you can access it like so:

```
$code = $request->input('code');
```

Then you can do whatever you want, like validate the code exists, etc.

You can learn more at the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: I want this prefix to be add after site url and rest route will work same as suppose route siteurl/contactus as siteurl/prefix/{dynamic code}/contactus without defining route again

Comment: See my updated answer. This would let you do `siteurl/user/blabla`. Just put all your routes within the callback function.